# Label groups in SQL records based on consecutive matching records

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

Given the below dataset

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
 ( A NUMERIC,
   B NUMERIC )

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (243184, 0);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (240719, 0);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (236482, 1);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (230777, 0);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (226023, 0);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (222522, 0);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (214977, 1);

SELECT *
  FROM #temp
 ORDER BY A DESC

A                                       B
--------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
243184                                  0
240719                                  0
236482                                  1
230777                                  0
226023                                  0
222522                                  0
214977                                  1
```

How can I obtain the following output?

```
A                                       B                                       C
--------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----
243184                                  0                                       1
240719                                  0                                       1
236482                                  1                                       2
230777                                  0                                       3
226023                                  0                                       3
222522                                  0                                       3
214977                                  1                                       4
```

I want to group consecutive instances of [B] records into groups based on the value of 'A' when sorted in descending value.

So that each time [B] flips from 0 to 1 a new group starts

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see the sense of the expected output, could you explain something better?

Comment: Tried changing the question does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT s.A, s.B
    ,SUM(s.IsChange) OVER (ORDER BY s.A DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) +1 AS [C]
FROM (
    SELECT t.A,t.B
        ,CASE WHEN t.B <> LEAD(t.B)OVER(ORDER BY t.A) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [IsChange]
    FROM #temp t
) s
ORDER BY s.A DESC
;
```

Comment: This does create the desired result set would you be able to explain the logic and how it works?

Comment: In subquery it compares current B with next B, if it changes it stores IsChange as 1. Then it sums that values (1) with all previous values which creates a "group" value.

Comment: English is my second language, SQL is my first :)